# Javascript Get Selected Radio Button Values

Tags: javascript, radio-button, nodelist

I have been tasked with coding some javascript to add a pizza to a 'basket'. I have a 'Add to Basket' button which needs to get the name, description, size and price of the pizza.

Currently, I have managed to get the name and description of the pizza from the 'Add to Basket' button but I also need to get the price and size of the pizza which is determined from what radio button the user selects.

The html code was given to me.

```
<td>   
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    <input id="size" name="Cheese" data-price="6.50" value="Small" type="radio" checked>Small
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="size" name="Cheese" data-price="8.50" value="Medium" type="radio">Medium
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="size" name="Cheese" data-price="9.99" value="Large" type="radio">Large
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td style="padding-top: 6px">£6.50</td>
                <td style="padding-top: 6px">£8.50</td>
                <td style="padding-top: 6px">£9.99</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</td>
<td>
    <input id="addbasket" name="Cheese" data-description="Mozzarella cheese" value="Add to Basket" type="button" onclick="addBasket(this)"> 
</td>
```

Here is the javascript, I was also asked to convert the NodeList to an array and then filter through that array to get the radio button that is checked which I think I have done with the first two lines.

```
function addBasket(button) {
    var nodes = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName(name));
    var radio = nodes.filter(function(el){return el.checked;})[0];

    var pizzaname = button.name;
    var pizzadesc = button.getAttribute('data-description');

    var pizzaprice = radio.dataset.price;
}
```

Now I don't know how to get the 'data-price' and the 'value' (size of pizza) from the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `radio.getAttribute('data-price')` to get the price of the pizza and `radio.value` to get the size of the pizza. Also note that you can avoid using `[].slice.call` by using `[].filter.call` on your NodeList.

```js
var name = 'Cheese'

function addBasket(button) {
  var nodes = document.getElementsByName(button.name)
  var radio = [].filter.call(nodes, function(e) {
    return e.checked
  })[0]

  var pizzaname = button.name
  var pizzadesc = button.getAttribute('data-description')

  var pizzasize = radio.value
  var pizzaprice = radio.getAttribute('data-price')

  console.log({
    Name: pizzaname,
    Description: pizzadesc,
    Size: pizzasize,
    Price: pizzaprice
  })
}
```

```html
<td>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr align="center">
        <td>
          <input name="Cheese" data-price="6.50" value="Small" type="radio" checked>Small
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Cheese" data-price="8.50" value="Medium" type="radio">Medium
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Cheese" data-price="9.99" value="Large" type="radio">Large
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td style="padding-top: 6px">£6.50</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 6px">£8.50</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 6px">£9.99</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
<td>
  <input id="addbasket" name="Cheese" data-description="Mozzarella cheese" value="Add to Basket" type="button" onclick="addBasket(this)">
</td>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at addBasket" for the pizzasize variable. An error for the pizzaprice variable too, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined at addBasket". One test i've been doing is to use alert(pizzaprice) and to see whether or not it says '6.50' if the radio button for small is checked but it either it comes up as 'undefined' or no alert will appear.

Comment: Did you try running the snippet I posted above (which works on my computer) and comparing the code to yours?

Comment: I've put it through again and works as expected so thank you. I've included more pizzas however with separate 'Add to Basket' buttons for each one and have called the same 'addBasket' function for its onclick. When pressing these buttons, they are all giving me the values of the first pizza. Any ideas on how to get the values for the pizza corresponding with the button that is clicked? The name and description are working as expected but the price and size are the values selected from the first pizza on the list.

Comment: You will need to set the same name for your input radio buttons as that on your add to basket button, and each pizza name distinct (e.g. `name="Pepperoni"` where you see a name of Cheese currently).

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.